# Have trouble installing an msi files

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux

To get around using Microsoft software such as Excel, I'm running play on linux.

I encountered a problem today that i can't seem to find a solution online. I have excel 2010 installed but now my teacher wants me to instal power query which is a msi file.

I have read through the documentation and i understand that to install msi files through wine i have to use

```
wine start filename.msi
```

or

```
wine msiexec /i filename.msi
```

The only problem i am having is that everytime i try to run the msi file it tells me that office is not installed etc... ive tried running the file from the wine or play on linux drives and even the virtual c drive but everytime i get this error.

Does anyone know from which folder i have to run the file to get it to instal this package to windows properly.

Comment: the MSI has to be run in the prefix that has MSOffice installed in it.  I'm not sure how to do this with PoL. but try opening PoL, select the MSOffice prefix and see if there is a "run in this Prefix" option.

Comment: I did a bit of work and found that the install is in PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/Program_Files/Microsoft_Office/Office14

I still couldn't run the msi file from this folder tho any help?

Comment: what is the full path? is it in ~/.local/share ?

Comment: No its in Home/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/Program_Files/Micr‌​osoft_Office/Office1‌​4

the executable file for excel is in this office14 folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can specify the prefix to run a command in via the command line. First open a terminal and navigate to the folder where the MSI program is located. Then type:

```
WINEPREFIX="~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010" wine start /unix ./filename.msi
```

this should launch the MSI in the office prefix.

Explination:

- WINEPREFIX -- specifies the prefix to run. The default prefix is used if this isn't specified.
- wine -- starts the wine server
- start -- tells wine to start the following prigram
- /unix -- tells wine that the following path is a linux path not a windows path
- ./ -- the current directory, it can be omitted but is good to avoid confusion.
- filename.msi -- the installer you want to run

Comment: Thz for the indetailed answer and explaining the commands it certainly helps.

I am still having some problems i assume your " " should be ommited and when entering the command line it should be 


`WINEPREFIX=/home/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010 wine start /unix ./filename.msi
`


when i enter that command it gives me back this line 


`wine: chdir to /home/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010
 : No such file or directory
`

Comment: because your files are under /home/<user>/  where <user> is your user name. `~` is a shorthand for /home/user. The " can be omited if there ar no spaces in the path names. However, the " also allows bash to use the shortcut notation ~ ... so in the example I gave the " is required. If you type the complete absolute path then they can be left off. The line I gave is exactly what you need to type, except replace "filename" with the actual file name.